# Ruby: Create Hot-Swap

Tags: ruby, hotswap

developers!

I'm currently working on a project in Ruby that requires me to be able to hotswap code whilst it's operating. However, the only method I know (because, to be honest, I am quite new to Ruby) is to do a full reboot, and that takes too long. Is this possible? Do I have to override my code? Include a console? Or something else?

I'd be glad if somebody could help me with my problem.

Best Regards

Comment: You cannot typically "hot-swap" code (without performing some weird hacks); that's not how ruby works. However, you can perform zero-downtime deployments (which *should* only take a few seconds, at least on  a small system). Can you provide more information about your application, so I can point you in the right direction for doing zero-downtime deployments?

Comment: Is it standalone ruby script? Rails? Sinatra? Is it running on a single server, or distributed (how?)? How are you deploying currently? What do you mean by "full reboot"?